# Redirect after form submission with ajax in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have form which is using Ajax to be submitted on WordPress. The form works fine and the information from it goes to the database and it is saved correctly.

The problem is that I can't get it to redirect to another page. The form is really simple

```
<form method="post" id="main">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_nonce' ); ?>

     <div class="columns is-multiline">
         <div class="column is-4">
             <input type="text" name="firstname" />
         </div>
         <div class="column is-4">
             <input type="text" name="middlename" />
         </div>
         <div class="column is-4">
             <input type="text" name="lastname" />
         </div>
     </div>
     <div id="success_message"></div>
         <div class="columns">        
             <div class="column is-3">
                 <input type="submit" name="submit-button" id="submit-button" value="Submit" />
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Then I have this in `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_ajax_scripts'); 
function my_ajax_scripts(){
    wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'myajax', array( 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url( '/admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_scripts'); 
function ajax_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'form', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/form.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

}

function form(){

        global $wpdb;

        if (!check_ajax_referer( 'my_nonce' )){
            wp_die();
        }

        $table = UPC_jobs;

        $formdata = $_POST['formdata'];

        parse_str($formdata, $formdata_array);

        $data = array(
            'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
            'middlename' => $_POST['middlename'],
            'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
        );

        $format = array(
            '%s', '%s', '%s',' %s'
        );        
        $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
        if($success) {
            wp_redirect( '/my-target' );
            wp_die();
        }
}
```

And if need the js part

```
$('#main').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var formdata = (window.FormData) ? new FormData(form[0]) : null;
    var data = (formdata !== null) ? formdata : form.serialize();

    formdata.append("action", "form");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: myajax.ajaxurl,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        status: 200,
        data: formdata,
        success: function( data ){     
            window.location.replace("https://example"); // this doesn't work as well 
        },          
    });         
});
```

When I click `Submit` nothing happen, absolutely nothing. All the info is stored in database as is should but the page doesn't react/show anything.

Also working solution would be to just show a message that the form is submitted successfully (not alert)

Comment: You can not do an HTTP redirect in response to an AJAX request, and expect that to have any effect on the frontend. So unless you want the response to the AJAX request to actually be what a request to `/my-target` would return, `wp_redirect( '/my-target' );` makes little sense in there. (And depending on what that response actually is, it might not go into the success handler either.)

Comment: any error on console?

Comment: No, nothing. Everything is clear and fine there.

Comment: remove this line and check `dataType: 'JSON',`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried instead of a success callback, use **always**?
In your case you can try this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: myajax.ajaxurl,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        status: 200,
        data: formdata            
    }).always(function() {     
       window.location.replace("https://example"); // this doesn't work as well 
    });
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't knew about `.always`. Is there a way to carry a message with the redirect also which I can show in `<div id="success_message"></div>`

Comment: @Jordan sure, you can put in **always** callback any code

Comment: You can add this to always callback    

`$('#success_message').show(); // show msg
setTimeout(function(){ // and  redirect in 2 seconds
window.location.replace("https://example");
}, 2000);
`

Is it work for you?

Comment: Also, with `always` it means that it will be showed always, even when the form failed, right?